# PHP: In OrangeHRM v4.1.1, how to apply some admin function into employee account

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony-1.4, orangehrm

[2 sides of the same link, left are admin, right is employee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3uc7.png)

The OrangeHRM framework works with 2 types of accounts, the admin and employee, the owner wants to add some functionality that's originally found only in the admin account to be added into the employee account. As such because many of the employees work in many different places and they need to change where they currently are each time they moved to a new place. And since the admin is not able to actively update those data, the owner would like the employee to change that data by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not too late.

You can do it by editing 'ohrm_user_role_data_group' table in the database.

Or Else you can enable other roles like Supervisor, ProjectAdmin, Interviewer, HiringManager, Reviewer in ohrm_user_role according to your need.